# List of Samba parameters?

Tags: windows, linux, samba

Where can I find a list of samba parameters? I've tried google but cannot find a list. Is there an official one somewhere?

Comment: Boy do I feel stupid (man smb.conf) http://us1.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html

Comment: If that's the answer to your question, you should post it as an answer as soon as the system lets you, and then accept it if it's still the best answer after a few minutes.

Comment: My account is anonymous, so no can do.

Answer (score 1):

I like this one. I think it is a little easier to read. http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html

Answer (score -1):

testparm --show-all-parameters